# sharing function name as class

Tags: php, class

if i have

```
class root_parser extends doc_parser {
 function xml_parser($filename, &$id)
{

parent::doc_parser($filename) 
}

}
```

in my code and this

in the included file

```
class doc_parser
{
public function doc_parser( $filename )
{some code here}
}
```

will this run the function doc_parser or just access the class? because I get Call to undefined function doc_parser() when using var_dump but it shows up in my backtrace

I don't want to run the function, I just want to know Will it run the function or not? and also why does it show up when I backtrace my code,

here is the code I am using for backtrace

```
array_walk(debug_backtrace(),create_function('$a,$b','print "{$a[\'function\']}()(".basename($a[\'file\']).":{$a[\'line\']}); ";'));
```

Comment: not enough information. Put all the necessary code. Where exactly do you call that code?

Comment: You're missing open and close brackets on the doc_parser method.

Comment: i don't want to call that code i just wonder does it call the function or just access the class if i have just that

Comment: @Toussant Landowner: " if i have just that" --- if you literally have **just that** - it's incorrect code, since `parent::` outside of any class method makes no sense. "i just wonder does it call the function or just access the class" --- this phrase makes no sense as well

Comment: oh i understand what you mean, i edited it, what i mean is that how to use this parent :: part ? will using parent :: (string) in this situation run an function or will it just access the class? I ask this because in this case the class and the function in that class share the same name

Comment: @Toussant Landowner: so you call parent method you've overriden. What's the question? They have the same name, so what?

Comment: ok so this just calls the parent class parent::doc_parser($filename) ? and if I want to access the function inside I just do this? $pages = $this->doc_parser($filename)?

Answer (score 0):

Check it by renaming the function or the class and see if the code works then. If it does then you know that the naming is the problem.